# Why is it printing both 'username found' and 'username not found'?

Tags: python

```
database=[['username1','password1'],['username2','password2']]

def get_username():
  username= input('enter username:')
  return username

def check_username():
  username=get_username() 
  for pair in database:
    if username==pair[0]:
      print('username found!')
    else:
      print('username not found.')
```

ouput:

```
enter username: username1
       username found!
       username not found.
```

Comment: Add a few more names to your database and you will see what is going on.

Comment: You're looping through the database list. Since there is two items in there, it's looping twice. If you add more, then there will be that many more loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code might help.

```
def check_username():
  username=get_username() 
  for pair in database:
    if username==pair[0]:
      print('username found!')
      return
  print('username not found.')
  return
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently what is happening in your code is, you iterate through your pairs correctly (bad indentation) and you check if user input is in a pair. If not it will print `not found`. Then it will move onto the second pair. If your username is found in that pair, you will receive `found`. So your output is ugly.

```
not found
found
```

Instead, I suggest, fixing your indentation. Iterate through your pairs, check if your username meets in any of the pairs. If I cannot find a match in any pair then I execute `else` which is waiting outside our for loop #Note: else is not needed, but for clarification, I will keep it there. But say we find the username in a pair, you execute the if and break out of the for loop.

```
database=[['username1','password1'],['username2','password2']]

def get_username():
  username= input('enter username:')
  return username

def check_username():
    username=get_username() 
    for pair in database:
        if username==pair[0]:
            return 'username found!'
    return 'username not found.'
print(check_username())
```

Comment: Just some few remarks: the `else` in `for` is unnecessary and you should print `check_username()`. Other than that, this is the best answer I've ever saw in Stackoverflow in my whole life. I'm literally crying right now.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are printing inside a for a loop.  The [python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) has a great example of how it works.

If you print `pair` inside `check_username` like this:

```
def check_username():
    username=get_username() 
    for pair in database:
        print(pair)
```

You will get:

```
['username1', 'password1']
['username2', 'password2']
```

So in the first list, your variable `username` will be equal to `pair[0]`, so the `username found!` will be print, but in the second list the variable `username` is different to `pair[0]`, so `username not found` will be print.

To fix this, the way to go in python is using a [for/else](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) block, like this:

```
def check_username():
    username=get_username() 
    for pair in database:
        if username==pair[0]:
            print('username found!')
            break
    else:
        print('username not found.')
```

Comment: @Silver in which line?

Comment: in your `if .. else..` statement of last code block

Comment: No, it is a for else block, check the link

Comment: Oh I see, unfamiliar, just find out that for/else is a thing in python.

Answer (score 0):

You need to exit out of your loop once the username is found. So include a break clause inside of your first conditional statement.